# Creating a full page border image with parallax scrolling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax, border-image

I'm trying to create a website with parallax scrolling and a full page border image in the foreground that all text/containers will go under as you scroll to down. I was thinking of splitting the border image into left & right side bars, a header, & footer, but I'm worried about the scalability of this. Is there a way to create a full page border image in the foreground with a transparent center where the body of the page will go while still having clickable links in the body of the page(technically the background)? I'm working with Rails 5, Bootstrap 3, and Skrollr for the parallax effect.

Right now the fix I have is:

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta tags...></meta tags>

<head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><%= image_tag 'header.png', style: 'width:100%;' %></nav>
  </head> <body>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="skrollr-body">

    <%= render 'layouts/application_layout' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar-left' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/sidebar-right' %>

    <%= yield %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false;
        smoothScrolling: true
    });
  </script>
  </div></body>
    <nav class="navber navbar-fixed-bottom"><%= image_tag 'footer.png', style: 'width:100%;' %></nav>
</html>
```

Here's the relevant css:

```
.sidebar-left {
    background-image: url('side-l.png');
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar-right {
    background-image: url('side-r.png');
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

head {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 102;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a working model right now using the left & right side bars, and header & footer all as images with higher z-index values than the body, but I don't like the way the sidebar images touch to the header/footer images. I think I can fix this in graphic design, but still looking for a better full page border image solution

Comment: please share what you have done so far

Comment: Just edited to add relevant code